# Two propositions about 2-adic order $\nu_2$

Tags: solution-verification, p-adic-number-theory

The $2$-adic order $\nu_2(x)$ of a nonzero integer $x$ is the highest power $k$ of $2$ such that $ 2^k $ divides $x$.

Consider these two propositions for a positive integer $n$ and odd numbers $x$ and $y$:

**(a)** If $4$ divides $x-y$, then $\nu_2(x^n-y^n)=\nu_2(x-y) + \nu_2(n).$

**(b)** If $n$ is even, then $\nu_2(x^n-y^n)=\nu_2(x-y)+\nu_2(x+y)+\nu_2(n)-1.$

Egnlish Wikipedia says that **(b)** is a stronger one. But I think **(a)** and **(b)** are equivalent because, if we assume **(a)**, we may prove **(b)** as follows:

*Proof (??) of (a) $\to$ (b).* Write $n=2m$. Then we have
$$ \nu_2(x^n-y^n) = \nu_2\left ((x^2)^m-(y^2)^m \right) = \nu_2(x^2-y^2)+\nu_2(m). $$
But $\nu_2(ab)=\nu_2(a)+\nu_2(b)$, we conclude that
$$ \nu_2(x^n-y^n) = \nu_2(x-y) + \nu_2(x+y) + \nu_2(n) -1. $$

Is this correct?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The source is here: https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjEttnLmarvAhVQ62EKHX0nBpwQFjAAegQICRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLifting-the-exponent_lemma&usg=AOvVaw3bndbmX788HGu4XoKigBFb

The document assumes $x$ and $y$ are both odd, so do I. Then $4$ indeed divides $x^2-y^2$.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I overlooked the oddity at first. Then your argument looks good to me.

Comment: I believe b is stronger because it's only contingent on $2$ dividing $x-y$ rather than $4$.